# R script for find the minimum distance

Tags: r, distance

I need an R code to select which polygon in a shapefile has got the minimum distance from a given point.

Comment: - [Distance of point feature to nearest polygon in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448402/distance-of-point-feature-to-nearest-polygon-in-r)
- [Calculating the distance between polygon and point in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294343/calculating-the-distance-between-polygon-and-point-in-r)
- and many others

Comment: @gene In subtle but very important ways the posts you reference are not duplicates of this one.  The best algorithms for selecting a minimum-distance polygon do *not* proceed by computing all polygon-to-point distances.

Comment: Have you tried anything?